# Semihosting printf fails in _malloc_r

Tags: c, printf, cortex-m

I'm trying to get a minimal project with printf semihosting (printf over JTAG) working on a [STM32F746NG Discovery](http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/32f746gdiscovery.html) development board and I'm running into trouble when printf is called. I'm at a loss for how to proceed in debugging this issue.

Here's the symptoms. The HardFault_Handler is called from _malloc_r which gets called by printf. Here is the stack when the HardFault_Handler is entered:

```
#0  0x08000424 in HardFault_Handler () at startup.c:155
#1  <signal handler called>
#2  0x08000d28 in _malloc_r ()
#3  0x0800215c in __smakebuf_r ()
#4  0x08002066 in __swsetup_r ()
#5  0x08001972 in __sfvwrite_r ()
#6  0x080018b2 in _puts_r ()
#7  0x0800036a in main () at main.c:41
```

The instruction at _malloc_r+96 causes the hard fault. If I set a breakpoint at _malloc_r+96 and continue 3 times, the processor hard faults after stepping over _malloc_r+96 the third time. Here is the output from GDB with the register information.

```
GNU gdb (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors 6-2017-q1-update) 7.12.1.20170215
-git
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Resetting target
Select auto target interface speed (2000 kHz)
Selecting device: STM32F746NG
Semi-hosting enabled (Handle on BKPT)
Semihosting I/O set to TELNET and GDB Client
Loading section .vectors, size 0x1c8 lma 0x8000000
Loading section .text, size 0x1fe4 lma 0x8000200
Loading section .rodata, size 0x1c lma 0x80021e4
Loading section .init_array, size 0x8 lma 0x8002200
Loading section .fini_array, size 0x4 lma 0x8002208
Loading section .data, size 0x848 lma 0x800220c
Start address 0x8000384, load size 10780
Transfer rate: 1315 KB/sec, 1796 bytes/write.
Resetting target
(gdb) b *_malloc_r+96
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8000ce8
(gdb) display/i $pc
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x8000384 <Reset_Handler>:   push    {r7, lr}
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, 0x08000ce8 in _malloc_r ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x8000ce8 <_malloc_r+96>:    ldr     r3, [r4, #4]
(gdb) i r
r0             0x49     73
r1             0x20000678       536872568
r2             0x1      1
r3             0x20000680       536872576
r4             0x84882528       2223514920
r5             0x20000008       536870920
r6             0x408    1032
r7             0x20000438       536871992
r8             0x0      0
r9             0x0      0
r10            0x0      0
r11            0x0      0
r12            0xffffffff       4294967295
sp             0x2004fb28       0x2004fb28
lr             0x48     72
pc             0x8000ce8        0x8000ce8 <_malloc_r+96>
xpsr           0x91090000       2433286144
msp            0x2004fb28       537197352
psp            0x0      0
primask        0x0      0
basepri        0x0      0
faultmask      0x0      0
control        0x0      0
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, 0x08000ce8 in _malloc_r ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x8000ce8 <_malloc_r+96>:    ldr     r3, [r4, #4]
(gdb) i r
r0             0x49     73
r1             0x20000678       536872568
r2             0xfffffbf8       4294966264
r3             0x0      0
r4             0x0      0
r5             0x20000008       536870920
r6             0x408    1032
r7             0x20000438       536871992
r8             0x0      0
r9             0x0      0
r10            0x0      0
r11            0x0      0
r12            0xffffffff       4294967295
sp             0x2004fb28       0x2004fb28
lr             0x48     72
pc             0x8000ce8        0x8000ce8 <_malloc_r+96>
xpsr           0x21090000       554237952
msp            0x2004fb28       537197352
psp            0x0      0
primask        0x0      0
basepri        0x0      0
faultmask      0x0      0
control        0x0      0
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, 0x08000ce8 in _malloc_r ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x8000ce8 <_malloc_r+96>:    ldr     r3, [r4, #4]
(gdb) i r
r0             0x49     73
r1             0x20000678       536872568
r2             0xbbc234f0       3150066928
r3             0xbbc238f8       3150067960
r4             0x77f2eed6       2012409558
r5             0x20000008       536870920
r6             0x408    1032
r7             0x20000438       536871992
r8             0x0      0
r9             0x0      0
r10            0x0      0
r11            0x0      0
r12            0xffffffff       4294967295
sp             0x2004fb28       0x2004fb28
lr             0x48     72
pc             0x8000ce8        0x8000ce8 <_malloc_r+96>
xpsr           0x81090000       2164850688
msp            0x2004fb28       537197352
psp            0x0      0
primask        0x0      0
basepri        0x0      0
faultmask      0x0      0
control        0x0      0
(gdb) si
0x080003ec in HardFault_Handler () at startup.c:149
149     void HardFault_Handler(void) { while(1) { } }
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x80003ec <HardFault_Handler+4>:
    b.n 0x80003ec <HardFault_Handler+4>
(gdb) i r
r0             0x49     73
r1             0x20000678       536872568
r2             0xbbc234f0       3150066928
r3             0xbbc238f8       3150067960
r4             0x77f2eed6       2012409558
r5             0x20000008       536870920
r6             0x408    1032
r7             0x2004fb04       537197316
r8             0x0      0
r9             0x0      0
r10            0x0      0
r11            0x0      0
r12            0xffffffff       4294967295
sp             0x2004fb04       0x2004fb04
lr             0xfffffff9       4294967289
pc             0x80003ec        0x80003ec <HardFault_Handler+4>
xpsr           0x81090003       2164850691
msp            0x2004fb04       537197316
psp            0x0      0
primask        0x0      0
basepri        0x0      0
faultmask      0x0      0
control        0x0      0
(gdb)
```

It looks like $r4 is getting clobbered. I'm at a complete loss as to how to debug and fix this issue. Am I not initializing the C environment correctly in startup.c? Am I not defining something correctly in the linker? Let me know if I need to add more information, clarify something, or try some test.

Some other details:

- STM32F746NG Discovery board. The onboard STLink debugger was reprogrammed using Segger's [STLinkReflash](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/other-j-links/st-link-on-board/) utility.
- GNU Tools ARM Embedded - 6 2017-q1-update
- Windows 7 x64

---

### startup.c

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>    

void Reset_Handler(void);
// __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void NMI_Handler(void);
// __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void HardFault_Handler(void);
// __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void MemManage_Handler(void);
// __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void BusFault_Handler(void);
// __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void UsageFault_Handler(void);
// __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void SVC_Handler(void);
// __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DebugMon_Handler(void);
// __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void PendSV_Handler(void);
// __attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void SysTick_Handler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void WWDG_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void PVD_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void TAMP_STAMP_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void RTC_WKUP_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void FLASH_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void RCC_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void EXTI1_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void EXTI2_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void EXTI3_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void EXTI4_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA1_Stream1_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA1_Stream2_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA1_Stream3_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA1_Stream4_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA1_Stream5_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA1_Stream6_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void ADC_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void CAN1_TX_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void CAN1_RX1_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void CAN1_SCE_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void TIM1_BRK_TIM9_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM11_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void TIM1_CC_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void TIM2_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void TIM3_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void TIM4_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void I2C1_EV_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void I2C1_ER_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void I2C2_EV_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void I2C2_ER_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void SPI1_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void SPI2_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void USART1_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void USART2_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void USART3_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void RTC_Alarm_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void OTG_FS_WKUP_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void TIM8_BRK_TIM12_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void TIM8_UP_TIM13_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void TIM8_TRG_COM_TIM14_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void TIM8_CC_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA1_Stream7_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void FMC_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void SDMMC1_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void TIM5_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void SPI3_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void UART4_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void UART5_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void TIM7_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA2_Stream1_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA2_Stream2_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA2_Stream4_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void ETH_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void ETH_WKUP_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void CAN2_TX_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void CAN2_RX0_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void CAN2_RX1_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void CAN2_SCE_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void OTG_FS_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA2_Stream5_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA2_Stream6_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA2_Stream7_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void USART6_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void I2C3_EV_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void I2C3_ER_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void OTG_HS_EP1_OUT_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void OTG_HS_EP1_IN_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void OTG_HS_WKUP_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void OTG_HS_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DCMI_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void RNG_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void FPU_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void UART7_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void UART8_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void SPI4_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void SPI5_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void SPI6_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void SAI1_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void LTDC_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void LTDC_ER_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void DMA2D_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void SAI2_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void QUADSPI_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void LPTIM1_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void CEC_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void I2C4_EV_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void I2C4_ER_IRQHandler(void);
__attribute__((weak, alias("Default_Handler"))) void SPDIF_RX_IRQHandler(void);


extern int main(void);
extern void SystemInit(void);
extern void __stack(void);

extern unsigned _sidata;
extern unsigned _sdata;
extern unsigned _edata;
extern unsigned _sbss;
extern unsigned _ebss;


void Reset_Handler(void)
{   
    SystemInit();

    memcpy(&_sdata, &_sidata, &_edata - &_sdata);
    memset(&_sbss, 0, &_ebss - &_sbss);

    main();
}


void Default_Handler(void)
{
    /* Spin forever */
    while(1) { }
}


void NMI_Handler(void) { while(1) { } }
void HardFault_Handler(void) { while(1) { } }
void MemManage_Handler(void) { while(1) { } }
void BusFault_Handler(void) { while(1) { } }
void UsageFault_Handler(void) { while(1) { } }
void SVC_Handler(void) { while(1) { } }
void DebugMon_Handler(void) { while(1) { } }
void PendSV_Handler(void) { while(1) { } }
void SysTick_Handler(void) { while(1) { } }


void __attribute__ ((section(".vectors"))) (*const vector_table[])(void) = 
{
    &__stack,
    Reset_Handler,

    NMI_Handler,
    HardFault_Handler,
    MemManage_Handler,
    BusFault_Handler,
    UsageFault_Handler,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    SVC_Handler,
    DebugMon_Handler,
    0,
    PendSV_Handler,
    SysTick_Handler,

    /* External Interrupts */
    WWDG_IRQHandler,
    PVD_IRQHandler,
    TAMP_STAMP_IRQHandler,
    RTC_WKUP_IRQHandler,
    FLASH_IRQHandler,
    RCC_IRQHandler,
    EXTI0_IRQHandler,
    EXTI1_IRQHandler,
    EXTI2_IRQHandler,
    EXTI3_IRQHandler,
    EXTI4_IRQHandler,
    DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler,
    DMA1_Stream1_IRQHandler,
    DMA1_Stream2_IRQHandler,
    DMA1_Stream3_IRQHandler,
    DMA1_Stream4_IRQHandler,
    DMA1_Stream5_IRQHandler,
    DMA1_Stream6_IRQHandler,
    ADC_IRQHandler,
    CAN1_TX_IRQHandler,
    CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler,
    CAN1_RX1_IRQHandler,
    CAN1_SCE_IRQHandler,
    EXTI9_5_IRQHandler,
    TIM1_BRK_TIM9_IRQHandler,
    TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler,
    TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM11_IRQHandler,
    TIM1_CC_IRQHandler,
    TIM2_IRQHandler,
    TIM3_IRQHandler,
    TIM4_IRQHandler,
    I2C1_EV_IRQHandler,
    I2C1_ER_IRQHandler,
    I2C2_EV_IRQHandler,
    I2C2_ER_IRQHandler,
    SPI1_IRQHandler,
    SPI2_IRQHandler,
    USART1_IRQHandler,
    USART2_IRQHandler,
    USART3_IRQHandler,
    EXTI15_10_IRQHandler,
    RTC_Alarm_IRQHandler,
    OTG_FS_WKUP_IRQHandler,
    TIM8_BRK_TIM12_IRQHandler,
    TIM8_UP_TIM13_IRQHandler,
    TIM8_TRG_COM_TIM14_IRQHandler,
    TIM8_CC_IRQHandler,
    DMA1_Stream7_IRQHandler,
    FMC_IRQHandler,
    SDMMC1_IRQHandler,
    TIM5_IRQHandler,
    SPI3_IRQHandler,
    UART4_IRQHandler,
    UART5_IRQHandler,
    TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler,
    TIM7_IRQHandler,
    DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler,
    DMA2_Stream1_IRQHandler,
    DMA2_Stream2_IRQHandler,
    DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler,
    DMA2_Stream4_IRQHandler,
    ETH_IRQHandler,
    ETH_WKUP_IRQHandler,
    CAN2_TX_IRQHandler,
    CAN2_RX0_IRQHandler,
    CAN2_RX1_IRQHandler,
    CAN2_SCE_IRQHandler,
    OTG_FS_IRQHandler,
    DMA2_Stream5_IRQHandler,
    DMA2_Stream6_IRQHandler,
    DMA2_Stream7_IRQHandler,
    USART6_IRQHandler,
    I2C3_EV_IRQHandler,
    I2C3_ER_IRQHandler,
    OTG_HS_EP1_OUT_IRQHandler,
    OTG_HS_EP1_IN_IRQHandler,
    OTG_HS_WKUP_IRQHandler,
    OTG_HS_IRQHandler,
    DCMI_IRQHandler,
    0,
    RNG_IRQHandler,
    FPU_IRQHandler,
    UART7_IRQHandler,
    UART8_IRQHandler,
    SPI4_IRQHandler,
    SPI5_IRQHandler,
    SPI6_IRQHandler,
    SAI1_IRQHandler,
    LTDC_IRQHandler,
    LTDC_ER_IRQHandler,
    DMA2D_IRQHandler,
    SAI2_IRQHandler,
    QUADSPI_IRQHandler,
    LPTIM1_IRQHandler,
    CEC_IRQHandler,
    I2C4_EV_IRQHandler,
    I2C4_ER_IRQHandler,
    SPDIF_RX_IRQHandler,
};
```

### main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern void initialise_monitor_handles(void);

int main(void)
{   
    initialise_monitor_handles();

    printf("Hello world!\n");

    return 0;
}

void SystemInit(void)
{

}
```

### memory.ld

```
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

__heap_size = 0x200;
__stack_size = 0x400;

MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 1024K
    RAM (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 320K
}

GROUP(
    libgcc.a
    libg.a
    libc.a
    libm.a
    libnosys.a
    librdimon.a
)

SECTIONS
{
    /***********************************************************************************************/
    /* VECTOR TABLE                                                                                */
    /***********************************************************************************************/
    .vectors :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.vectors))
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } > FLASH


    /***********************************************************************************************/
    /* PROGRAM CODE                                                                                */
    /***********************************************************************************************/
    .text :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
        *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
        *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
        *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
        *(.eh_frame)

        KEEP (*(.init))
        KEEP (*(.fini))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
    } > FLASH


    /***********************************************************************************************/
    /* CONSTANT DATA                                                                               */
    /***********************************************************************************************/
    .rodata :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __rodata_start__ = .;
        *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
        *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __rodata_end__ = .;
    } > FLASH

    .ARM.extab : 
    {
        *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
    } > FLASH

    .ARM.exidx :
    {
        __exidx_start = .;
        *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
        __exidx_end = .;
    } > FLASH

    .preinit_array :
    {
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
        KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
    } > FLASH

    .init_array :
    {
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
        KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
        KEEP (*(.init_array*))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
    } > FLASH

    .fini_array :
    {
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
        KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
        KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
    } > FLASH

    _etext = .;


    /***********************************************************************************************/
    /* INITIALIZED DATA                                                                            */
    /***********************************************************************************************/
    .data : ALIGN(4)
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);
        _sdata = .;
        __data_start__ = .;
        *(.data)
        *(.data*)

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _edata = .;
        __data_end__ = .;
    } > RAM AT > FLASH


    /***********************************************************************************************/
    /* UNINITIALIZED DATA                                                                          */
    /***********************************************************************************************/
    .bss (NOLOAD) : ALIGN(4)
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        PROVIDE(_sbss = .);
        __bss_start__ = .;
        *(.bss)
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)

        . = ALIGN(4);
        PROVIDE(_ebss = .);         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
        __bss_end__ = .;
    } > RAM


    /***********************************************************************************************/
    /* USER HEAP                                                                                   */
    /***********************************************************************************************/
    .heap (NOLOAD) : ALIGN(4)
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        PROVIDE(end = .);
        __heap_start = .;
        __heap_base__ = .;
        . = . + __heap_size;
        __heap_end = .;
        __HeapLimit = .;
    } > RAM


    /***********************************************************************************************/
    /* USER STACK                                                                                  */
    /***********************************************************************************************/
    .stack ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM) - __stack_size (NOLOAD) :
    {
        __stack_start = .;
        __stack = .;
        *(.stack)
        . = . + __stack_size;
        __stack_end = .;
        __StackLimit = .;
    } > RAM


    /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
    /*/DISCARD/ :
    {
        libc.a ( * )
        libm.a ( * )
        libgcc.a ( * )
    }*/

    .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

### makefile

```
CC   = arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD   = arm-none-eabi-gcc
SIZE = arm-none-eabi-size

ARCHFLAGS = -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard
CFLAGS    = -g -c -Wall -Werror -pedantic 
LDFLAGS   = --specs=rdimon.specs -lc -lrdimon -Wl,--gc-sections,-Map,main.map,-Tmemory.ld

SOURCES = main.c startup.c
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)

main.elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(ARCHFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)
    $(SIZE) --format=sysv -x $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(ARCHFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

clean:
    rm -rf main.elf
    rm -rf $(OBJECTS)
    rm -rf main.map
```

### .gdbinit

```
file main.elf
target remote :2331
monitor reset
monitor halt
monitor speed auto
monitor flash device STM32F746NG
monitor semihosting enable
monitor semihosting IOclient 3
load
monitor reset
```

Comment: We seem to have very different ideas about what a [mcve] is.

Comment: Sorry for the verbosity. I don't know what else to remove from the example files above. My inspiration was https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/224618/minimal-code-required-to-startup-a-stm32f4 but with semihosting enabled. I tried to include just the information required to compile and debug my target microcontroller.

Comment: Perhaps I should have posted in electronics.stackexchange?